# Counting xyz_ids in QWEB

Tags: odoo-13, qweb

I am trying to create a conditional block that will display a table with n>0 records. That is to say that if there are no records, the table is not displayed:

```
<t t-if="len(order_ids) > 0">
    <table style="width: 100%;">
        <thead>
            <tr style="border-bottom: 0.5px solid LightGray">
                <th style="width: 50%">SO</th>
                <th style="width: 50%">Amount</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody style="border-bottom: 0.5px solid LightGray">
            <t t-foreach="record.order_ids.raw_value" t-as="o">
                <tr>
                    <td><t t-esc="o.name"/></td>
                    <td>$<t t-esc="o.amount_total"/></td>
                </tr>
            </t>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</t>
```

The model in question is `crm.lead`, and I am trying to count the `order_ids` field.
`order_ids` is a `one2many` field. The error I am getting is:

> TypeError: dict.len is not a function

[Though it is](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/dictionary_len.htm)

How can count the amount of ids of a `one2many` field directly in a QWEB template?

Answer (score 0):

I think `<t t-if="record.order_ids">` or if you put `order_ids` in a variable  `<t t-if="order_ids">` should be enough.